# validate whether the extra variable value is correct in ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook which requires `--extra-vars` to be passed and would like to know if there is any way to validate that the value is one of the list values which is defined.

Sample **`test.yml`**

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    prod_mgmt_network: "{{ ['server00'] | product(range(start,end)) | map('join') | list }}"
    start: 4281
    end: 4283

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: prod_mgmt_network
```

Sample command

```bash
ansible-playbook --extra-vars hostName=server004181 test.yml
```

I want a task that will fail the execution if `--extra-vars` `hostName` value is not one of variable is define.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either an [`assert`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) or [`fail`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html) task.

### Using assert

```
- name: check that variable is defined using assert
  assert:
    that: hostname|default('') is in prod_mgmt_network
    fail_msg: "hostname is not in prod_mgmt_network"
```

Which results in:

```
TASK [check that variable is defined using assert] ********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "hostname is defined",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "hostname is not in prod_mgmt_network"
}
```

### Using fail

```
- name: check that variable is defined using fail
  when: hostname|default('') is not in prod_mgmt_network
  fail:
    msg: "hostname is not in prod_mgmt_network"
```

Which results in:

```
TASK [check that variable is defined using fail] **********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "hostname is not in prod_mgmt_network"}
```

Comment: still pass the task even though the hostname is not within the variable

Comment: I thought you wanted to check if the variable was defined. If you want a different test, then use these examples but modify the failure condition...or update your question to be more explicit about what you want to verify.

Comment: I've updated the examples to do what I think you want, based on your comment.